# Does it make sense to end email with: regards from *country*

Tags: writing-style, email

I have seen many people say:

> Greetings from [country name here]

But would it make sense to end an email with

> Regards from [country name here]

It seems a little weird, specially if I also put a name below it:

> Regards from Italy,
>
> Bob

Comment: Sure it makes sense, especially if you want to emphasize the physical separation. What's weird is that I can't find *Itay* on the map.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, so long as you spell the country correctly.

Comment: haha I was thinking what Martin meant when he said he couldn't find Italy on the map. I just noticed... well this is awkward. I will fix the spelling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course I owe this to the good people above   Martin Krzywinski & Hot Licks: nothing wrong with " Regards from Italy,
Bob." I am reminded with the famous Bond's movie [From Russia with Love](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_Russia_with_Love_%28film%29) which became a famous saying ( I mean: From...with love) in [press](http://www.economist.com/news/middle-east-and-africa/21645229-leaked-cables-cast-seedy-light-second-oldest-profession-pretoria) and literature.

It can be of course written: with love from...; regards from.